# Tuleap how to support Agile teams who have different ways of working

Tags: tuleap

We have a Tuleap project where many teams are working.  The project is configured for doing agile planning.  Currently the sprint cardwall has the following columns:  Not Started, In Progress, and Done.  The task tracker is one of the trackers that can be planned in a sprint and has the same statuses (Not Startd, In Progress and Done).  One of the teams would also like to have Pending and Cancelled in the sprint cardwall (artifacts when put in that column take on the status of the column).  How can this be achieved without affecting other teams.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want a sprint cardwall to have different properties depending on which team it belongs to. The problem is that the cardwall columns are defined on a given milestone type (e.g. sprint).

One option would be to create a different sprint tracker for the other team and set-up a new agile dashboard planning accordingly.

Comment: Actually I did the following:  (1) Created a new Sprint2 and Task2 trackers (2) Update the tracker hierarchies as follows Sprint and Sprint2 are children of the Release tracker and a User Story has Task and Task2 as children.  I created a new Planning in the Agile Dashboard, Sprint2Planning where I can plan User Stories and Task2 trackers in Sprint2 tracker.  However the problem is that when I go to the Agile Dashboard and click new Sprint, it does not open the Sprint2 tracker  but rather the Sprint tracker.  Tuleap seem to ignore the Sprint2 as it is at the same level as sprint.